# Does ∇⋅τ = μΔv in the Cauchy Momentum Equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics, navier-stokes

I find two versions of the Cauchy momentum equation ([1](https://community.dur.ac.uk/suzanne.fielding/teaching/BLT/sec1.pdf), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#General_continuum_equations)):
$$
\rho \frac{D\vec{v}}{Dt}=\rho\vec{g} - \nabla{p} + \mu\nabla^2\vec{v}
$$
$$
\rho \frac{D\vec{v}}{Dt}=\rho\vec{g} - \nabla{p} + \nabla \cdot \bf\tau
$$
where $\tau$ is the stress tensor and $\vec{v}$ is the fluid velocity.

I'm tempted to conclude that $\mu\nabla^2\vec{v} = \nabla \cdot \bf\tau$. However, when I expand and compare terms on both sides of the equation they look widely different.

Does this equality actually hold? If so, what is the physical relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stress tensor is related to velocity in a **Newtonian fluid** as
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\tau_{ij} = \mu\left(\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}\right)
\end{equation}
If we assume that the **viscosity of the fluid is independent of its position** then the divergence of stress is
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\frac{\partial\tau_{ij}}{\partial x_j} = \mu\frac{\partial^2 v_i}{\partial x_j^2} +
\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_j}\right).
\end{equation}

If we further assume that the **fluid is incompressible** then $\nabla\cdot\vec{v} = 0$ so that equation (2) simplifies to
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\frac{\partial\tau_{ij}}{\partial x_j} = \mu\frac{\partial^2 v_i}{\partial x_j^2}.
\end{equation}

It is under these assumptions (marked **bold**) that $\nabla\cdot\tau = \mu\nabla^2\vec{v}$.

You may find the third chapter of Batchelor's book interesting if you wish to know more about this topic.

Comment: I’ve seen equation (1) with an additional pressure times Kronecker delta term. What determines if the term is included?

Comment: Thank you! This really helped.

Comment: The total stress is sometimes split into a symmetrical component (-p $\delta_{ij}$) and a deviatoric component (equation (1) in my answer). I have considered only the deviatoric part.